# How to extract a set of number from a string after a "triggering word"

Tags: regex, perl

I'm a beginner to Perl and Regular Expression. I want to extract certain amount dollar after $. So I write the following code. However, I try to avoid the first $ sign, that is, I only want the information after word "My" in this case.

```
my $str = 'His house is small; only worth $90,000;My house is so big; it worth $179,000; ';
if ( $str =~ /\$([\d,]+)/) {
my $used = $1;
print "House Price: $used\n";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you guys rock.

Comment: you need to accept one and bring logical closure to this question

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*\bMy\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\$([\d,]+)
```

You can use `(*SKIP)(*F)` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/52

Answer (score 1):

```
My.*?\K\$\d+(,\d+)?
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/vL0aE9/2)

---

The idea is:

- `My` - find `My`
- `.*?` - match the least amount of characters until you get to a `$` sign
- `\K` - [drop everything matched so far](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) (so it's not included in the result)
- `\$\d+(,\d+)?` - support either integers or float amount of `$`s

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = 'His house is small; only worth $90,000;My house is so big; it worth $179,000; ';
if ( $str =~ /My.*?\$(\d+,\d+)?/) {
    my $used = $1;
    print "House Price: $used\n";
}
```

> House Price: 179,000